# Excel function for indexing and matching multiple criteria

Tags: excel

Say I have the following column headings filled with data on Sheet2:

```
| Station number | Year | Month| Rainfall (mm) |
       XX1         1995    1       30
       XX1         2005    4       50
       XX1         2004    5       70
```

...

And the following columns on Sheet1:

```
|Year | Month of Max | mm | Month of Min | mm |
 2004     
 2005
 2006
```

...

I have the following code under the "Month of Max" column:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B2:B10000,MATCH(MAX(Sheet2!D2:D10000),Sheet2!D2:D10000,0))
```

However, I want to match the years too (i.e. the year in `Sheet1!A2` should match the year in `Sheet2!B2:B10000` for looking up the maximum rainfall). I can't figure out where to put this function and keep getting errors. Sorry if this is obvious or has been asked before, I'm just very stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MATCH` is not suited to matching multiple creiteria.  An alternative is this

```
=MAX(IF(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10000=Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!$D$2:$D$10000,""))
```

enter as an Array Formula (press Ctrl-Shift-Enter rather than just Enter)

The `IF` part returns an array, with entries for non-matching years set to a null String.  `MAX` then gets the maximum value of that array